# How do I place my app window in a certain position in the desktop window hierarchy on Windows using win32 api?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want my application window to be in a certain spot in the window hierarchy. That is, say I have 3 windows on my desktop. At the very bottom I have Word, the window on top of word is explorer, and the active foreground window is itunes. I want to place my application window on top of word but beneath explorer. How can I achieve this with win32?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545(VS.85).aspx) - look at the hWndInsertAfter parameter. I'm not sure if this will work across process boundaries, but it's worth a shot. Perform this after your window is created but before you make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not possible, because you will get caught by the code that tries to prevent focus stealing - it might work if your app initially has focus and you try to give it away (i.e. you are on top, then you try to hide behind the Explorer window)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain this arrangement, the simplest way is to create your window specifying Words window as your parent

Otherwise SetwindowPos is the all purpose worker for controlling a windows position, visibility and depth. But any z-ordering performed here will obviously be lost as soon as the user actually starts switching tasks.

One thing to watch out for: windows always raises the active window to the top of the z-order, and likewise, activates any window that is moved to the top of the z-order. There are restrictions however :- to prevent all manner of irritating behaviour Windows prevents applications from stealing activation without a user interaction - which means that, if word is currently the active window, SetWindowPos to place yourself above Word will only succeed if your app is allowed to take activation at that time.